# How to avoid function boilerplate because of move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Do I have to write two methods for everything with a parameter? Like one for passing via reference and one for passing via move semantics? 
The same for ctors. If a ctor has 2 arguments do I have to write 4 ctors for every combo with move and reference? 
How can I avoid writing everything a couple times?

Comment: No, you don't. An MCVE would help us to show you the actual code, but usually you simply pass by value and than move from it.

Comment: This is what universal or forwarding references are for. If you wish to pass a const ref, however, you probably have to create 2 or more signatures. In this case however pass by value is a viable option.

Comment: I really don't see why this question wwas closed. Its about general programming techniques and not about debugging or about a particular bug.

Comment: @MikeMB: The question should focus around an example that illustrates the described problem. Otherwise, answers may end up addressing tangential issues.

Comment: I will add an example as fast as possible I am sorry

Comment: Pay attention to motivate why you feel you need to write a move version in addition to a reference version.